# Song lyrics help with grammar explanation / repair?

Tags: grammaticality, lyrics

I ended up on German party songs area of the Internet the other day (once again) and could not help but to wonder about the correct grammar:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgfNsek8xkc

According to lyrics
"Doch eins sei dir gesagt"

I suppose English meaning somehow translates to

"But.. there is one thing someone should tell you."

It feels like this is smug-pokerface-german, that some words lack in German version for grammar to be "correct", or am I mistaken? I am not so used to this word "sei". I don't think we had it in back school very much.

Maybe it is some dialect? I mean lyrics also contain "Vadder" (and not "Vater"). 
I know that "Vader" is Dutch so maybe it is sung in some nether dialect?

Comment: @CarstenS : Aha okay, but what about Vadder, is it general German word and not dialect?

Comment: *Vadder* is Low German.

Comment: Yes, *Vadder* is dialect. Wikipedia tells me that the band is from Bremen, so your comparison with Dutch is spot on, this is a low German influence. Generally, the lyrics are standard German, though.

Comment: OMG Бременские Музыканты! лол..

Comment: @mathreadler, not exactly ;) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Bremer_Stadtmusikanten

Comment: @CarstenS Yep it was a reference to them. Or more specifically the version known in Russland. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHeRDRAxowQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the literal English equivalent would be:

> Let one thing be said (to you).
> "Let one thing be clear."

*Sei*, in this instance, is formally third person singular present subjunctive. The meaning is that of an optative, i.e. a wish. The same could be expressed periphrastically with *sollen*.

> Eins soll dir gesagt sein.

The construction seems like run-of-the-mill German to me. Further examples:

> Eins sei nicht vergessen. / Eins soll nicht vergessen sein.
> Let one thing not be forgotten.
> "Let's not forget one thing."
>
> Nur so viel sei verraten. / Nur so viel soll verraten sein.
> Let only this much be revealed.
> "We'll only reveal this much."
>
> Die wichtigsten Punkte seien noch einmal wiederholt.
> Let the most important points be reiterated.
> "Let's reiterate the most important points."

For another example where English has *let* and German a subjunctive, see Genesis 1:3:

> Let there be light!
> Es werde Licht!

To see that *sei* is not imperative in the above examples, compare a case where it is:

> Sei gewiß, daß nichts dein Eigentum sei, was du nicht inwendig in dir hast. (Matthias Claudius)
> Rest assured that nothing is your property that you do not have within you.

Note that the verb is in first position and that the unrealized subject is the addressee (***you** rest assured*), whereas in the subjunctive examples, the verb occurs in second position and the subject is overtly realized, not a person and not the addressee.

The song is in Standard German. The lenition of the internal consonant and shortening of the stressed vowel of *Vater* – going from [ˈfaːtɐ] to [ˈfad̥ɐ] – is widespread in northern colloquial German. The only other obvious deviations from Standard German I could spot are the diphthongization of the vowel in *schon* right at the beginning and the form *Jung* (tending towards *Jong*) instead of *Jungen* ([2:48](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgfNsek8xkc&t=2m48s)).

Comment: Imperative (*Werde, Licht!*) makes no sense at all – who is addressed? to do what? Grammatically, the presence of a subject (*eins*, which is not the person or thing being addressed) and the impossibility of V1 order (\**sei eins dir gesagt*) should be sufficient to establish that *sei* is not imperative in these cases.

Comment: I am convinced, I was wrong, it is a subjunctive, indeed.